# “Exceptionally, I play tennis.” – Odd use of “exceptionally”?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

The following uses of “exceptionally” (by a non-native speaker) seem odd to me. Even though at least one dictionary shows such usage, I get no corpus hits, so I suspect that this usage is odd. And if odd, what would be a more natural expression?

> Your argument was **exceptionally** considered.
>
> **Exceptionally**, the application was rejected.
>
> Option 2 is available **exceptionally**.

If these examples are *not* odd, then the following should be ok:

> I usually play tennis, but **exceptionally** I play golf.
>
> I usually play tennis, but I **exceptionally** play golf.
>
> I usually play tennis, but I play golf **exceptionally**.

But none of these examples seems natural to me.

However,  at least one dictionary, Macmillan, lists this very usage:

> **[exceptionally](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/exceptionally)**
>
> in a way that is different from what happens in other cases or
>   situaions
>
> *Exceptionally, candidates with other qualifications will be considered for admission to the course.*

But, when I do a corpus search to see if this is actually used:

**Ngram  Search**

"Exceptionally he": No hits

"Exceptionally she": No hits

"Exceptionally it": No hits

**[Univ. Michigan Student Paper Corpus](http://eli-corpus.lsa.umich.edu/)**

14 hits. But all for "exceptionally" before an adjective, such as "exceptionally accurate," which seems a *normal* usage.

Comment: I am a non-native speaker, having English as the first language and I too find such a use of 'Exceptionally' exceptional.

Comment: @Satnam How exceptionally funny, which is an *exception*.

Comment: Your premise is wrong here: the fact that your first three sentences are fine (they're quite, well, unexceptional to me, except perhaps the second one) does not entail that the next three are. Grammatically they're similar; but semantically they're different. In the first, _exceptionally_ means “as a deliberate and specifically per-case-based exception to the general rule” (i.e., the argument would not normally have been considered, but because of reasons XYZ, an exception was made); this makes no sense in your latter three sentences (_occasionally_ is meant), which is why they're so odd.

Comment: If you don't like them (and I don't, either), just say "as an exception."

Comment: You need to know that "I usually play tennis, but I play golf exceptionally" does not indicate _occasionally_. It means you play golf very well (exceptional compared with others). Similarly, there is a joke that says if you must recommend a lazy worker, say "I can assure you that you will be _lucky_ to have him perform _any_ work for you at all."